# Flutter: Image button circled

Tags: flutter

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qiEF.png)

i d like to centralize 3 image buttons at the screen one on top of the other with a onpressed in each of them below there is my  start code.

```
class Escolha extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(     
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(         
    ),
    body: Material(          
     elevation: 4.0,
       shape: CircleBorder(),
      color: Colors.transparent, 
       child: Ink.image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/logotipo.png'),
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 100.0,
           height: 120.0,
            child: InkWell(
               )    
                 )  
                   )
                ),
              );
           }
         }
```

Comment: Can you also share the screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: tks for you reply CopsOnRoad i dont have a screenshot i imagine a simple rounded image (3 of them) one on top of other in the center of the screen with a onpressed link

Comment: I'm sorry but it is difficult to know exactly what you need. If possible you can draw on a piece of paper and share the image here. I will try my best to implement it.

Comment: CopsOnRoad i found a image that can be usefull pls see on the top of the topic the link to the image tks!

Comment: Is that all you want? Should I put the code of drawing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the UI of the image you have mentioned in the link. Here is the working code.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                height: 2.0,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Image.asset("assets/four.png"),),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                height: 2.0,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Image.asset("assets/three.png"),),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                height: 2.0,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Image.asset("assets/two.png"),),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                height: 2.0,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Image.asset("assets/one.png"),),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                height: 2.0,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much CopsOnRoad.

Comment: Glad to hear, you can replace images with `IconButton` I used `Image.Asset` for simplicity.